# How to filter symbols in string by mask?

Tags: python, regex

How to filter symbols in string by mask ?

For example, I have simple string:

```
"tes!@#$%^&*(())___+t" "test1" "test3N"
```

How to delete symbols NOT IN "a-zA-Z", for example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple, use a negative character class in regex:

```
import re

re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', inputstring)
```

`[....]` denotes a character class. Normally, anything in the class matches. By adding the `^` caret at the start you negate the class; anything *not* in the class matches.

Result:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', '"tes!@#$%^&*(())___+t" "test1" "test3N"')
'testtesttestN'
```